# C# - Send and Receive data from USB device

Tags: c#, usb

I have a requirement to detect USB and send/receive data from it periodically. I am new to Windows programming. I have successfully implemented function to detect the USB device. Now to open connection and send data I have written the following code

```
     static void OpenConnection()
        {
            SerialPort port = new SerialPort();
            port.PortName = "COM1";
            port.Parity = Parity.None;
            port.BaudRate = 9600;
            port.DataBits = 8;
            port.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            port.Handshake = Handshake.RequestToSend;
            port.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 8;
            if (port.IsOpen)
            {
                port.Close();
                port.Dispose();
            }

            byte[] bytesToSend = new byte[8] { 0X00, 0X01, 0X02, 0X03, 0X04, 0X05, 0X06, 0X07 };
            port.Open();
            port.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);

            port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
            port.Close();
            port.Dispose();
        }
```

And to read data,

```
        private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort port = (SerialPort)sender;
            int bytes = port.BytesToRead;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bytes];

            if (port.BytesToRead > 1)
            {
                port.Read(buffer, 0, bytes);
            }
        }
```

The problem is it is not working. The requirement is to send 8 bytes data to USB device (which is a temperature sensor) and the device will return 8 bytes of data. This should be repeated for every 5 seconds. Also the data should be sent to endpoint 1 and data will be received from endpoint 2.

As per the device documentation, it doesn't require driver and if we send 8 bytes of data, it will respond with 8 bytes of data.

Any advice/suggestion here is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Attach the `DataReceived` handler before you open the port and don't dispose of the SerialPort right after. The `if (port.IsOpen) { ... }` check also needs refactoring (if you dispose of it at that point, what happens next?).

Comment: Sure @Jimi. I'll try it out.